# Can't start unicorn, master failed to start, check stderr log for details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, production-environment, unicorn

I dont know what’s wrong with the unicorn.rb file. my unicorn.rb config is

```
APP_PATH = "/var/www/demo"
working_directory APP_PATH

stderr_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"

pid APP_PATH + "/tmp/pid/unicorn.pid"
```

running nginx successful.

```
sudo servier nginx start
sudo unicorn -c /var/www/demo/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

Comment: what does the stderr log at /var/www/demo/log/unicorn.stderr.log say? BTW, you're logging stdout and stderr to the same file.

Comment: No such file or directory - /path/to/.unicorn.sock (Errno::ENOENT)

Answer (score 8):

The socket is the "file" that nginx and unicorn use as a channel for all communication between them. Where have you defined it? In our unicorn configs, we usually have a line like this:

```
listen APP_PATH + "/tmp/pid/.unicorn.sock
```

Then, in your nginx.conf, you need to tell nginx about this socket, e.g.:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/var/www/demo/tmp/pid/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

location / {
  root /var/www/demo/current/public ;
  try_files $uri @unicorns;
}

location @unicorns {
  proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}
```

In this config file, the first section defines how nginx can reach unicorn. The second one actually routes requests to an abstract location "@unicorns" which, in turn, is defined in the last section. This way you can reuse the @unicorns shorthand if your have more complex nginx routing going on.